# Converting XML to another Xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml is as given below :

```html
<items>
    <item id='10' name='item1'/>
    <item id='20' name='item2'/>
    <item id='30' name='item3'/>
     <item id='40' name='item4'/>
    </items>

    <parent_group>
    <parent_group_item item_id='10' parent_group_id='30'/>
    <parent_group_item item_id='20' parent_group_id='30'/>
    </parent_group>
```

I want to convert the above code snippet to the below format using xsl:

```html
  <items>
    <item>
    <id>10</id>
    <name>    item1    </name>
    <parent_group_id>30</parent_group_id>
    </item>
    <item>
    <id>20</id>
    <name>    item2    </name>
    <parent_group_id>30</parent_group_id>
    </item>
    <item>
    <id>30</id>
    <name>    item3    </name>
   
    </item>
    <item>
    <id>40</id>
    <name>    item4   </name>
   
    </item>
    </items>
```

could you please help i need  it using xslt only.and i cannot hard code any values as the values are very dynamic.

Comment: The example is a bit thin. Can one assume all the required items are found inside the `<parent_group>`? And are you sure you want to lose the name/s of the parent item/s? --- Note also that your inout example is missing a root element!.

Comment: No all the items would not be part of a <parent_group> as some items would be independent on their own.Yes the parent item names are not important in this example.So The independent items would not have a <parent_group> element in them.

Comment: "*No all the items would not be part of a <parent_group> as some items would be independent on their own.*" Please post an example showing that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for code.

Comment: i have edited the post in order to make it more clear michael thanks

Comment: @torazaburo I have rolled back  your edit. I don't think this is the proper way to make your views known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input Xml Looks like so (i.e. has a root element):

```
<xml>
    <items>
    <item id='10' name='item1'/>
    <item id='20' name='item2'/>
    <item id='30' name='itemParent'/>
    </items>

    <parent_group>
    <parent_group_item item_id='10' parent_group_id='30'/>
    <parent_group_item item_id='20' parent_group_id='30'/>
    </parent_group>
</xml>
```

You can then use `key` to lookup the item_ids in the `parent_group_item` elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="parentGroup" match="parent_group_item" use="@item_id" />

    <xsl:template match="xml/items">
        <items>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <item>
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </id>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </name>
        <xsl:variable name="parentGroupKey" select="key('parentGroup', @id)" />
        <xsl:if test="$parentGroupKey">
            <parent_group_id>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('parentGroup', @id)/@parent_group_id"/>
            </parent_group_id>
        </xsl:if>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Updated to omit the `parent_group_id` element if it is unmatched.

Comment: You should define the key to `match="parent_group_item" use="@item_id"`. Then use `<xsl:value-of select="key('parentGroup', @id)/@parent_group_id"/>` to get the parent id value. Currently, your result is incorrect.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks very much - I wasn't paying enough attention to my code.

Comment: Thanks Stuart,Micahel made the appropriate changes and fixed the code thanks a ton.